# Align text in RecyclerView with titles

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-recyclerview

Hello I have made a RecyclerView with orders. But the list in the popup isnt't aligned with the titles. Because pictures say more than words, here you can see it:

[image]

But what I need is something like that:

[image]

How could I make this work? How can I nicely define the columns so that each article fits nicely under the heading?

Here is my RecyclerView:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="center">



        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/order_overview_artikel"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Artikel"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:textSize="16dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/order_overview_anzahl"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Anzahl"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:textSize="16dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/order_overview_preis"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Preis"
            android:textSize="16dp"/>



</LinearLayout>
```

And this is the pop up:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:gravity="center">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/white"
        app:cardCornerRadius="15dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
                android:orientation="vertical">


                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                        android:text="Bestellübersicht"
                        android:textAlignment="center"
                        android:textSize="25dp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"></TextView>

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/order_overview_number"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                        android:text="0"
                        android:textAlignment="center"
                        android:textSize="25dp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                        android:text="Produkt"
                        android:textAlignment="center"
                        android:textSize="18dp"
                        android:textStyle="bold">

                    </TextView>

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                        android:text="Anzahl"
                        android:textAlignment="center"
                        android:textSize="18dp"
                        android:textStyle="bold">

                    </TextView>

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                        android:text="Preis"
                        android:textAlignment="center"
                        android:textSize="18dp"
                        android:textStyle="bold">

                    </TextView>

                </LinearLayout>

                <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:clipToPadding="true"
                        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

                        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                            android:id="@+id/recyclerview_order_scroll"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent">

                        </androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>
                    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>


                </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

                <com.airbnb.lottie.LottieAnimationView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="128dp"
                    app:lottie_autoPlay="true"
                    app:lottie_loop="true"
                    app:lottie_rawRes="@raw/walkingburger" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn_order_overview_finish"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/button_order_checkout"
                    android:backgroundTint="#9BC3BF"
                    android:elevation="16dp"
                    android:text="FERTIG"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.777" />


            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a similar layout pattern for title layout and the recycler view item. It's

use

```
android:weightSum="3"
```

and for child views set the layout_weight as 1. All three will be aligned.
I have made changes to your code.

RecyclerView Item

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="3"
    android:gravity="center">



    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/order_overview_artikel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Artikel"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:textSize="16dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/order_overview_anzahl"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Anzahl"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:textSize="16dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/order_overview_preis"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Preis"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textSize="16dp"/>



</LinearLayout>
```

Your popup

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
android:gravity="center">

<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/white"
    app:cardCornerRadius="15dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                    android:text="Bestellübersicht"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textSize="25dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"></TextView>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/order_overview_number"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                    android:text="0"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textSize="25dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:weightSum="3"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:text="Produkt"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textSize="18dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold">

                </TextView>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:text="Anzahl"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textSize="18dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold">

                </TextView>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:text="Preis"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textSize="18dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold">

                </TextView>

            </LinearLayout>

            <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:clipToPadding="true"
                    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

                    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                        android:id="@+id/recyclerview_order_scroll"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent">

                    </androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>
                </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>


            </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

            <com.airbnb.lottie.LottieAnimationView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="128dp"
                app:lottie_autoPlay="true"
                app:lottie_loop="true"
                app:lottie_rawRes="@raw/walkingburger" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_order_overview_finish"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/button_order_checkout"
                android:backgroundTint="#9BC3BF"
                android:elevation="16dp"
                android:text="FERTIG"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.777" />


        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! :) I wish you the best. Much Money and all of the worlds health! :)

Comment: Happy Coding!  I wish you the same. :)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, in your pop, for "Produkt", "Anzahl" and etc. you write layout_width like "match_parent", but in your RecyclerView layout_width of items is wrap_content. Change layout_width on match_parent in your RecyclerView.

Answer (score 0):

You need a table view layout in order to align texts, you can also use linear layout but it tricky and complex UI solution which performs quite heavy operations on the UI layer to render (example using weights in linear layout).
Check this android official [link](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/grid) for more understanding.

Comment: How can this be used in the context of recyclerview?